Why is Brave Browser preemptively downloading files?
Sometimes, when I was downloading large artifact archives from a GitLab project (~500 MB) in my Brave Browser I was positively surprised when it was partially done already from the start (varying from 20% to up to 70%).
I suspect that it had identified the download link and began downloading preemptively while I was still reading the trace.

Does Brave indeed feature integrated logic for preemptive downloading (Or Chromium, which it is based on as far as I know)?
Are there security risks linked to such a feature?
Can this be turned off if needed?


Apparently, others have that issue, too: https://community.brave.com/t/how-to-disable-automatic-downloading-of-files-that-begin-downloading-before-i-click-to-save-to-folder/478373 . One can turn off all automatic downloading by making Brave request the location to save files...


Does Brave indeed feature integrated logic for preemptive downloading (Or Chromium, which it is based on as far as I know)?

Most web browsers, including the ones based on Chromium and also Firefox, offer such a feature whenever you open a link with downloadable content and choose where to save it. It is assumed you made the choice of downloading it and thus the process is sped up. While you're looking for a proper destination and name, it might already be almost available on your disk. It saves time for the most typical users.

Are there security risks linked to such a feature?

Not really, for the following reasons:

Downloading files does nothing by itself most of the time, executing them is the problematic part. Unless your system is already hacked or configured in a weird way to automatically run such downloaded files. Or you open an application that will run it for some reason. There were e.g. cases of antivirus programs having vulnerabilities that triggered from scanning such files.
The file will have a temporary extension and won't be complete until you accept its name in the save location popup. If you cancel, the file will be removed.
You can configure browsers to not even ask for a save location and automatically download to e.g. Downloads
The main security measure should be not clicking on suspicious links in the 1st place


Can this be turned off if needed?

I'm quite sure that's not an option. There might be some flag you can turn off, but I couldn't find any info about it.
